# Saving point cloud data into a file

Tags: processing, kinect, point-cloud-library

I have the following code working on `Processing 2`, with `Kinect`:

```
import org.openkinect.freenect.*;
import org.openkinect.processing.*;

// Kinect Library object
Kinect kinect;

// Angle for rotation
float a = 0;

// We'll use a lookup table so that we don't have to repeat the math over and over
float[] depthLookUp = new float[2048];

void setup() {
  // Rendering in P3D
  size(1200, 800, P3D);
  kinect = new Kinect(this);
  kinect.initDepth();

  // Lookup table for all possible depth values (0 - 2047)
  for (int i = 0; i < depthLookUp.length; i++) {
    depthLookUp[i] = rawDepthToMeters(i);
  }
}

void draw() {

  background(0);

  // Get the raw depth as array of integers
  int[] depth = kinect.getRawDepth();

  // We're just going to calculate and draw every 4th pixel (equivalent of 160x120)
  int skip = 4;

  // Translate and rotate
  translate(width/2, height/2, -50);
  rotateY(a);

  for (int x = 0; x < kinect.width; x += skip) {
    for (int y = 0; y < kinect.height; y += skip) {
      int offset = x + y*kinect.width;

      // Convert kinect data to world xyz coordinate
      int rawDepth = depth[offset];
      PVector v = depthToWorld(x, y, rawDepth);

      stroke(255);
      pushMatrix();
      // Scale up by 200
      float factor = 200;
      translate(v.x*factor, v.y*factor, factor-v.z*factor);
      // Draw a point
      point(0, 0);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }

  // Rotate
  a += 0.015f;
}

// These functions come from: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/Kinect.html
float rawDepthToMeters(int depthValue) {
  if (depthValue < 2047) {
    return (float)(1.0 / ((double)(depthValue) * -0.0030711016 + 3.3309495161));
  }
  return 0.0f;
}

PVector depthToWorld(int x, int y, int depthValue) {

  final double fx_d = 1.0 / 5.9421434211923247e+02;
  final double fy_d = 1.0 / 5.9104053696870778e+02;
  final double cx_d = 3.3930780975300314e+02;
  final double cy_d = 2.4273913761751615e+02;

  PVector result = new PVector();
  double depth =  depthLookUp[depthValue];//rawDepthToMeters(depthValue);
  result.x = (float)((x - cx_d) * depth * fx_d);
  result.y = (float)((y - cy_d) * depth * fy_d);
  result.z = (float)(depth);
  return result;
}
```

I would like to save `pointcloud` data in a file, so I can import it later on another program, such as `Cinema 4D`.

how do I create this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing has several functions for saving data to file, the simplest of which is [`saveStrings()`](https://processing.org/reference/saveStrings_.html).

To use the `saveStrings()` function, you would simply store whatever you wanted to save into a `String array`, and then pass that into the function along with a filename.

You can then use the [`loadStrings()`](https://processing.org/reference/loadStrings_.html) function to read the data from a file back into a `String array`.

How you format the data into a `String` is entirely up to you. You might store it as comma separated values.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

If you want to store the data into a file that another program can read, you have to first look up exactly what format that file needs to be in. I'd start by opening up some example files in a basic text editor.